# Android Studio -: Whenever I click on a class name while pressing CTRL in Android Studio, the new class open up in the place of existing class

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I click on a class name while press CTRL in Android Studio, the new class open up in the place of existing class, it is very frustrating. Is there a way to get around this issue?
I am not able to work properly because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the Android studio settings, try the following:

- Disable Open declaration in the same tab if enabled: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206569349/comments/360000225180
- Maybe preview tab is your troublemaker - You can also disable it: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/11/intellij-idea-2020-3-eap7/#preview_tab